# TypeError TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, postman

i am no several days try to figure out a solution for the failure (type error) below without luck.
For some reason it comes with this error below and I can't find a solution for it
or debugging so that I know what's wrong.

To put things in context.  I have a running app.py which is trying to execute some authorization in  auth.py with checking permissions of a token (that I pass on with Postmen)

```
************************
TypeError
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/ml_1/class-demos/Project_Fyyur/Files/Project_Fyyur-master/projects/capstone/starter_capstone_ml/starter/app.py", line 85, in <module>
@requires_auth('get:actors')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
*********************************


**Auth.py**

#AUTH0_DOMAIN = os.getenv('AUTH0_DOMAIN')
AUTH0_DOMAIN = 'fsnd-ml-casting-agency.eu.auth0.com'
ALGORITHMS = ['RS256']
API_AUDIENCE = 'Casting'

## AuthError Exception
'''
AuthError Exception
A standardized way to communicate auth failure modes
'''
class AuthError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, error, status_code):
        self.error = error
        self.status_code = status_code

def get_token_auth_header():
        auth = request.headers.get('Authorization', None)
        print(auth)
        if not auth:
            raise AuthError({
                'code': 'authorization_header_missing',
                'description': 'Authorization header is expected.'
            }, 401)

        parts = auth.split()
        if parts[0].lower() != 'bearer':
            raise AuthError({
                'code': 'invalid_header',
                'description': 'Authorization header must start with "Bearer".'
            }, 401)

        elif len(parts) == 1:
            raise AuthError({
                'code': 'invalid_header',
                'description': 'Token not found.'
            }, 401)

        elif len(parts) > 2:
            raise AuthError({
                'code': 'invalid_header',
                'description': 'Authorization header must be bearer token.'
            }, 401)

        token = parts[1]
        return token

def verify_decode_jwt(token):
    jsonurl = urlopen(f'https://{AUTH0_DOMAIN}/.well-known/jwks.json')
    jwks = json.loads(jsonurl.read())
    unverified_header = jwt.get_unverified_header(token)
    rsa_key = {}
    #print("jwsks",jwks)
    for key in jwks["keys"]:
        if key["kid"] == unverified_header["kid"]:
            rsa_key = {
                "kty": key["kty"],
                "kid": key["kid"],
                "use": key["use"],
                "n": key["n"],
                "e": key["e"]
            }
           
    if rsa_key:
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(
                token,
                rsa_key,
                algorithms=ALGORITHMS,
                audience=API_AUDIENCE,
                issuer="https://"+AUTH0_DOMAIN+"/"
            )
            return payload

        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            raise AuthError("token has expired", 401)
        except jwt.JWTClaimsError:
            raise AuthError("invalid claims (Error): check the audience", 401)
        except Exception:
            raise AuthError("invalid header: Unable to parse token", 401)

    print("rsa_key",rsa_key)     
    raise AuthError("invalid header: Unable to find right key", 401)

    def requires_auth(permission=''):
        def requires_auth_decorator(f):
            #print(permission)
            @wraps(f)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                try:
                    token = None
                    if session['token']:
                        token = session['token']
                    else:
                        token = get_token_auth_header()
                    print('token at authorization time: {}'.format(token))
                    if token is None:
                        abort(400)
                    payload = verify_decode_jwt(token)
                    print('Payload is: {}'.format(payload))
                    print(f'testing for permission: {permission}')
                    if check_permissions(permission, payload):
                    print('Permission is in permissions!')
                    
                    return f(payload, *args, **kwargs)
                except Exception:
                    abort(401)
    
    
            return wrapper
        return requires_auth_decorator 
    **End Auth.py**
#  Actors
#  ----------------------------------------------------------------
# route handler to get list of actors
        @app.route('/actors', methods = ['GET'])
@cross_origin()
@requires_auth('get:actors')
def list_actors(payload):
#def get_actors():
    #auth_header = request.headers['Authorization']
    #print ("Aut_header:", auth_header)
    #header_parts =  auth_header.split(' ') [1]
    #print("header_part", header_parts)
    # payload_data = check_permissions('permission','payload')
    # print("payload_data-1111", payload_data)
    token_data = requires_auth('token')
    print("token_data", token_data)
    #decorator_data = requires_auth('requires_auth_decorator')
    decorator_data = requires_auth('f')
    print("dec_data"), decorator_data
    actors = Actor.query.all()
    actors_data = []
    for actor in actors:
        actors_data.append({
            "id": actor.id,
            "name": actor.name,
            "age": actor.age,
            "gender": actor.gender,
            "image_link": actor.image_link
            })
        result = actors_data    

    return jsonify(result)
```

Comment: It is looking for a function named `get_actors` and is not able to find one, probably you have renamed it to `list_actors`, so maybe you need to do changes here `@requires_auth('get:actors')` accordingly

Comment: get:actors is the permission that the code will have to check in the given token. and list_actors is just the name of the def. Can u explain further what I need to change ? I can then test it.

Comment: I can't see a function named `get_actors` in your code. (its declaration) is commennted. Please check

Comment: Whenever you get a `NoneType` error, your first thought should be to look for the function that returns `None` or is missing a return altogether.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can't find the decorator function `requires_auth` which could be due to how `Auth.py` is being imported into `app.py`

Try this

1. Copy the contents of `Auth.py` directly into `app.py`
2. Run the code again and see if the problem goes away

You also have a decorator `cross_origin` which is not visible in your sample code. Make sure it is not overwriting something else

Updates on March 11

1. Try `import Auth` and then you can do `@Auth.requires_auth`

Comment: i have done this without luck , the error pesist... and I have comments the @cross origin , I can see that the whole token is passed correctly with a print statement

Comment: i have copied the whole piece of code of auth.py... maybe I am missing something ?

Comment: Hi NoCommandLine Now  it is working after copying all my code from auth.py in the app.py, but I can't  figure out why the import of auth.py is not imported properly into my app maybe the setup of my folders, but in that case my app should give a warning of not finding my auth.py

Comment: How exactly did you do the import? Try updating the code sample in app.py to show your import of auth.py. It is also most likely due to the folder structure. See if you can include a screen shot

Comment: from auth import AuthError, requires_auth, check_permissions, verify_decode_jwt                    I import my auth.py with the above statement in my app.py , I saw something like the folder structure could be the cause. but don't know how to fix it. I have a root folder where there is an auth.py folder and it, there is the auth.py, in the root there s my env folder and my app.py.

Comment: what strange is that when I use the db init, migrate I get the same error:xport FLASK_APP=app.py
export FLASK_ENV=development # enables debug mode
python3 -m flask db init   File "/Users/ml_1/class-demos/Project_Fyyur/Files/Project_Fyyur-master/projects/capstone/starter_capstone_ml/starter/app.py", line 254, in <module>
    @requires_auth('get:actors') TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: I've updated my answer (see updates on March 11)